# JSON sending to server

Tags: php, android, json

I have to send some JSON data to server from my android app.

Here is the code I have written.

```
public static String POST(String url, String id, int status, String cardno,String orderno){
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = "";

    try {

        // 1. create HttpClient
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpclient.getParams(), 10000);
        // 2. make POST request to the given URL
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        String json = "";

        // 3. build jsonObject
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("order_number", orderno);
        jsonObject.put("id", id);
        jsonObject.put("status", status);
        jsonObject.put("card_no", cardno);

        JSONArray postjson=new JSONArray();
        postjson.put(jsonObject);


        // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
       // json = jsonObject.toString();
       // httpPost.setParams("json", json.toString());
        System.out.println("json is"+jsonObject.toString());
        httpPost.getParams().setParameter("jsonpost", postjson);

        // 5. set json to StringEntity
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);

        // 6. set httpPost Entity
        se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,
                "application/json"));
        httpPost.setEntity(se);



        // 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

        // 9. receive response as inputStream
        inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

        // 10. convert inputstream to string
        if(inputStream != null)
            result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
        else
            result = "Did not work!";

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    // 11. return result
    System.out.println("result is"+result);
    return result;
}


private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line = "";
    String result = "";
    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        result += line;

    inputStream.close();
    return result;

}
```

And the php script to receive this in a text file is as:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
    file_put_contents("postData.txt",$_REQUEST);

    if(isset($_REQUEST['jsonpost']))
    {
        echo 'passed';
    }else{
        echo "NOT RUNNING";
    }
    exit;
?>
```

while i am executing the code from android app, my request is being done to connect to server  but I am not able to get any data in the text File.

What am i missing?
How should I send data to server?
Error is in my android code to send data or in the php script to receive it?

I have the modified code as:

```
 public static String POST(String url, String id, int status, String cardno,String orderno){
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = "";

        try {

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpclient.getParams(), 10000);
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            String json = "";
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("order_number", orderno);
        jsonObject.put("id", id);
        jsonObject.put("status", status);
        jsonObject.put("card_no", cardno);
        JSONArray postjson=new JSONArray();
        postjson.put(jsonObject);
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString());
        httpPost.setEntity(se);
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        ResponseHandler responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
        inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
        if(inputStream != null)
            result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
        else
            result = "Did not work!";

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    System.out.println("result is"+result);
    return result;
    }

    private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = "";
        String result = "";
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            result += line;
        inputStream.close();
        return result;
    }
```

But it still doesn't work. Any changes to be made in my php script?

Comment: Sorry missed the php script.

Comment: <?php

error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
 file_put_contents("postData.txt",$_REQUEST);
 
 if(isset($_REQUEST['jsonpost']))
 {
  echo 'passed';
 }else{
  echo "NOT RUNNING";
 }
 exit;

?>

Answer (score 2):

Try setting your post data to request like this:

```
//passes the results to a string builder/entity
StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString());

//sets the post request as the resulting string
httpPost.setEntity(se);

//sets a request header so the page receving the request
//will know what to do with it
httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

//Handles what is returned from the page 
ResponseHandler responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost, responseHandler);
```

Please note that this is not complete code, just the part that complements your code, so please use it in your example (all vars are named the same as you named them so it should be quite easy :) ).

Also make sure that your JSONObject has `jsonpost` key because when you post it like this, `key->values` from JSONObject will become `key->values` in your `$_POST` variable.

Comment: i tried following your solution. Sorry but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

`$_REQUEST` is an array like `$_POST & $_GET` so assuming you just want to know whats there and are not after any sort of elegant display `print_r()` it

```
file_put_contents("postData.txt",print_r($_REQUEST, true));
```